# Update file with multiple values automatically

Tags: command-line, aws, json

I have a hosted zone and record set that route to multiple addresses. I'd like to update the record set with adding or removing one IP address in the list. Unfortunately, AWS CLI doesn't provide the option of deleting/adding the value of resource record in route53

```
{
      "Comment": "Update the A record set",
      "Changes": [
        {
          "Action": "UPSERT",
          "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "mydomain.com",
            "Type": "A",
            "TTL": 300,
            "ResourceRecords": [
              {
                "Value": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I can add multiple IP addresses into your json like this manually. ***But I want to add multiple IPs to the json file using bash automatically.***

```
{
    "Comment": "Update the A record set",
    "Changes": [{
        "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "mydomain.com",
            "Type": "A",
            "TTL": 300,
            "ResourceRecords": [{
                    "Value": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: bash is just a shell, so I replaced that with [tag:command-line]; I wasn't sure why [tag:clipboard] was involved.  Perhaps you can specify the interaction you'd like to take place for this replacement? What's the input and resulting command?

Comment: If you definitely want to do this on the command line as a one-time workaround `jq` is the definite tool for it. If you want to produce a production-level tool to do this automatically and reliably you should try a language like Python or Ruby - they are much better suited for dealing with nested data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding, using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
$ jq '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords += [{"Value": "foobar"}]' file.json
{
  "Comment": "Update the A record set",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "mydomain.com",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
          },
          {
            "Value": "foobar"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It prints the output on the terminal, but how do I save the file with the changes? And what is the command to add multiple values?

Comment: I don't see that jq has a "save in place" option (might be wrong here), so you pipe the output into `> tmpfile && mv tmpfile file.json`

Comment: To add multiple items, just add more objects into the array: `+= [{"Value":"1"}, {"Value":"2"}, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

you may want to give it a try to another unix utility: *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)*, it's capable of applying modifications in-file (with `-f` option):

```
bash $ jtc -w'<ResourceRecords>l' -i'{ "Value": "YY.YY.YY.YY" }' -f file.json
bash $ jtc file.json 
{
   "Changes": [
      {
         "Action": "UPSERT",
         "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "mydomain.com",
            "ResourceRecords": [
               {
                  "Value": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
               },
               {
                  "Value": "YY.YY.YY.YY"
               }
            ],
            "TTL": 300,
            "Type": "A"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Comment": "Update the A record set"
}
bash $
```

and also deleting entry(ies):

```
bash $ jtc -w'<ResourceRecords>l [0]' -p -f file.json
bash $ cat  file.json 
{
   "Changes": [
      {
         "Action": "UPSERT",
         "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "mydomain.com",
            "ResourceRecords": [
               {
                  "Value": "YY.YY.YY.YY"
               }
            ],
            "TTL": 300,
            "Type": "A"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Comment": "Update the A record set"
}
bash $
```